# drag drop only one button inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

hello I am creating a web app in which I want to drag and drop a button inside a div,

I found something in w3schools and after a work-around did something like the following

[image]

but I want if I drag and drop second button in div,

the first should change its position and go back to origional position,

I created a fiddler which is not working

[not working fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/gu5sj6pm/)

following is my code

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<button id="test" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">button 1</button>
<button id="test2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">button 2</button>
<button id="test3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">button 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correct, you want only a single button per time inside the droppable area, right?

You can wrap the buttons in a `div`, then when you drop some button in the droppable area, check if the droppable already has a children element (in this case, a `button`). If yes, then select it and append it back to the `div` that is the buttons holder.

Something like the below code:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let target = ev.target;
    let btnsHolder = document.getElementById("buttonsHolder")
    let currentBtn;
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    
    //check if there's already a button inside
    if (target.children.length > 0){
      currentBtn = target.children[0];
      btnsHolder.appendChild(currentBtn);
    }
    
    target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));    
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<div id="buttonsHolder">
  <button id="test" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">button 1</button>
  <button id="test2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">button 2</button>
  <button id="test3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">button 3</button>
</div>
```